# How to change data of children with useState?

Tags: reactjs, children, use-state

```
const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState({
   "time": null,
   "blocks": [
      {
         "key": 1,
         "data": "This is some data"
      }
   ]
});
```

How can I use setBlocks to change "data" to "this is some other data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set method of useState not only accepts data, but also accepts functions.

```
setState(prevState => {
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```

So you can write something like this.

```
setBlocks(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  blocks: prevState.blocks.map(v => {
    return (v.key === 1)
      ? {...v, data: 'this is some other data'}
      : v;
  }),
});
```